# Browser hangs when sending ajax request 30 or more times

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, css

I want to show my data using the Next, Previous, First and Last buttons.

When I click on Next and Previous button 30 or more times, my browser will hang and ajax will not respond.

Please see the below code:

Main page script

```
<button id="lastbutton" onclick=" getlastinformation();">Last</button>
<button id="previousbutton">Previous</button>
<button id="nextbutton" onclick="getnextinformation();">Next</button>
<button id="firstbutton" onclick="getfirstinformation();">First</button>

<input type="hidden" id="change_id" name="change_id">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="typedescription" readonly>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cityname" readonly>

function getfirstinformation()
{
    document.getElementById('change_id').value = first_element;
    put_data(first_element);
}
function getnextinformation()
{
    var next_element = parseInt(document.getElementById('change_id').value);
    if(next_element!=last_element)
        next_element++;
    document.getElementById('change_id').value = next_element;
    put_data(next_element);
}
function getpreinformation()
{
    var pre_element = parseInt(document.getElementById('change_id').value);
    if(pre_element!=first_element)
        pre_element--;
    document.getElementById('change_id').value = pre_element;
    put_data(pre_element);
}
function getlastinformation()
{
    var last = localStorage.getItem("val");
    if(last==null)
        last = last_element;
    else
    {
        last = localStorage.getItem("val");
        localStorage.clear();
    }
    document.getElementById('change_id').value = last;
    put_data(last);
}
function put_data(val)
{
    // Add this line for next previous from Search Button
    var id = array_of_records[val]['id'];
    getalldata(id); 
}

function getalldata(val) 
    {
      $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_account.php",
    data:'id1='+val,
    success: function(data)
        {
            var supplier_array = new Array();
            supplier_array = data.split("|");
            $(".get-code").val(supplier_array[0]);
            $("#typedescription").val(supplier_array[23]);
            $("#cityname").val(supplier_array[24]);
        }
     });
}
```

Ajax requested URL file code

```
    get_account.php

    $customer_details = "";
    if(!empty($_POST["id1"])) 
     {
        $query ="SELECT * FROM `ledger WHERE id = '" . $_POST["id1"] . "' ORDER BY id DESC";
        $results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        while($state=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
        {
            $customer_details = $state["id"]."|".$state["type"];
            
            $query2 ="SELECT description FROM type WHERE type = '" . $state["type"]. "' ";
            $results2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
            while($state2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results2))
            {
                $customer_details = $customer_details."|".$state2["description"];
            }   

            $query3 ="SELECT cityname FROM citymast WHERE citycode = '".$state["citycode"]."' ";
            $results3 = mysqli_query($connection, $query3);
            while($state3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results3))
            {
                $customer_details = $customer_details."|".$state3["cityname"];
            }
        }
        }
    echo $customer_details;
```

Abort code in my ajax request function

```
    var currentRequest = null; 


    function getalldata(val) { 
    currentRequest = $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    data:'id1='+val, 
    url: "master/get_account.php", 

    beforeSend : function(){ if(currentRequest != null) 
     { currentRequest.abort(); } }, 

    success: function(data) { 
        var supplier_array = new Array(); 
        supplier_array = data.split("|"); 
        $("#typedescription").val(supplier_array[23]); 
        $("#cityname").val(supplier_array[24]); } }); }
```

How can I fix the above code such that it fixes the hanging of the browser when sending button clicks 30 or more times?

Comment: try to abort previous ajax call when new ajax call is performed.

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer but Still it is not working..

Comment: Here is my Aboert code in my ajax reuest function.... `var currentRequest = null; 
 
 function getalldata(val) 
 {
 currentRequest = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data:'id1='+val,
  url: "master/get_account.php",
  beforeSend : function(){           
        if(currentRequest != null) {
            currentRequest.abort();
   }
  },
  success: function(data)
   {
    var supplier_array = new Array();
    supplier_array = data.split("|");
    $("#typedescription").val(supplier_array[23]);
    $("#cityname").val(supplier_array[24]);
   }
  });
 }`

Comment: You can edit your question. Click this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44644374/edit. and edit your question with your tried code of abort which you have put in comment. I will solve error from that code.